# Prevent jQuery from double html encoding a string

Tags: jquery, html-encode

I am trying to convert an unordered list into a `<select>` box for people with small resolutions, indenting the text depending on the level in the list. To do this, I prepend the string with `&nbsp;`. However it looks like jQuery, for some reason, is double HTML-encoding this into `&amp;nbsp;`. How do I prevent this behavior and use a literal `&nbsp;` (i.e. so that a non-breaking space character is shown to the browser):

```
var text = '';
var i;

for (i = 0; i < level; i++) {
    text += '&nbsp;';
}
text += el.text();

if (el.hasClass('noclick')) {
    $('<optgroup />', {
        'label' : text
    }).appendTo('#menu select');
}
else {
    $('<option />', {
        'value' : el.attr('href'),
        'text' : text
    }).appendTo('#menu select');
}
```

Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hnRS/1/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `\u00A0` (the non-breaking space character) instead of `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the literal non-break space character in your JavaScript scripts with `\xA0`:

```
text += '\xA0';
```